# Is there a way to simply load records in crm?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, onload-event

I wrote some code in javascript that manipulates field info for my contact form. The code is triggered at OnLoad and OnSave. It works well but the company has 5000+ records that need this code to be applied to it.

Is there a way to write code or plug-in or workflow that would simply load the record and then close it that I could use on all records to apply the javascript or do I have to load each record individually?

Comment: What exactly is the action you are performing? It could be as simple as creating a workflow and then running it across all the applicable records (which is very easy to do).

Answer (score 3):

You could do one the following depending on what you find the easiest:

- Console Application (Personal Preference and the easiest) - Get the record unique numbers if you have something set up or GUIDs of the records
  you want updated
- Plugin (Some sort of record update required to trigger your logic) - add a throw away field - Register the plugin on update of the throw away field, use bulk update and update the field on all the records you want the plugin to run against. Delete the throw away field.
- Workflow (custom workflow activity or out of the box depends on the complexity of the manipulation, no record update required to trigger your logic) - Create a workflow/custom workflow activity and run it against all the records - it will probably take an eternity for you to get all 5000 updated at a maximum of 250 a go.

Comment: what does the Console Application entail?

Comment: Console application how to step by step -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695803(v=crm.7).aspx

Comment: Thank you but that seems a bit beyond the scope of my abilities. How would I go about doing it in a workflow?. I looked into it briefly but couldn't find anything that would help.

Comment: Edited my answer, if it is a simple operation like updating an option set value or updating a text you can just use out of the box CRM workflows, else, you will have to end up writing a custom workflow activity (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509012.aspx) which going to be a bit more complicated given that you find console application complex.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of the easiest ways to do what you want is to simply export the desired records and fields, and then manipulating them in Excel. You would apply the same logic in Excel as you have in your form JavaScript.
Once you're done, just import them back into CRM and the existing records should be updated.

The most important thing to pay attention to is that you export only after selecting the option "Make this data available for re-importing by including required column headings".
[image]